Build .NET8 projects without internet connectivity
I want to build a .NET8 project without internet connectivity. Earlier i was able to do when i was able to copy the cached packages to a machine where network connectivity isn't there and i was able to build successfully.
With .NET8 i am unable to figure out the location where the project stores the cached packages and uses them for build. I mean to which location the .NET8 projects download and store the packages when the machine has internet connectivity, so that i can copy them over to the machine and use them to build without the need to have network connectivity.
Below is the error.
error NU1301: Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.


on first use, NuGet creates a default nuget.config file in your user profile with nuget.org as a package source. Edit the nuget.config file and remove the line.  Running dotnet nuget remove source nuget.org should achieve this.

@zivkan If i remove the nuget.org entry from nuget.config file where does it look for the packages

The fallback folder in the fallbacklocation.config points to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages ,but i think the packages in that location are from the installation of VS

https://www.codurance.com/publications/2015/05/04/creating-a-local-nuget-repository

NuGet downloads packages to the "global packages" folder. You can find the location by running dotnet nuget locals all --list.

@zivkan I did try that but the none of the packages are available in those locations

@MatthewWatson Thank you. I am not looking for the custom nuget packages. I am looking for microsoft system packages which are required when build a .NET Core project

From your description, you don't need official public nuget source api, so just remove it in the visual studio settings and add the souce you want(Global nuget.config will sync after you save the changes):

By the way, remember to clear the nuget cache to make sure the restore use the package you specify:


But i think any .NET Core project will have few default packages that it needs for compilation,i was referring to figure out where the default packages will be available. I still remember for .NET6 and prior it was %userprofile%/.nuget where the default packages are downloaded and used. But from .NET8 i don't see any default packages being downloaded to that particular location

@subbaraoc Hi, could you please explain what is the 'default package'? 'C:\Users\Administrator.nuget\packages' is already the 3rd or some official package cache place(Also the .NET 8.0). using 'dotnet nuget locals all --list' is correct to list the packages, so do you mean you want where the original dll files are stored? If yes, check these path: 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework'(.Net Framework), 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'(.NET Core).
